# Can't mount docker container's working directory to host

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-build

I'm trying to build a docker container for my python application that allow edits to a config file in the application's working directory so I don't need to rebuild the image every time a change is made.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

VOLUME /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Once the image is built I deploy the container with

```
docker run -d --name app -v /path/on/host/app:/app app:latest
```

I get an error in the container, `python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` and `/path/on/host/app` stays empty.

I can't figure out what I need in my Dockerfile to make this work.

#### Update - Found a solution

Since I only need access to the config file here are the changes I made to get this to work

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install requirements.txt
VOlUME /app/config
CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

Now when I run the container I copy the config to `/path/on/host/app`

```
docker run -d --name app --mount type=bind,source=/path/on/host/app,target=/app/config
```

This solved my issue and now I can update the config and restart the container to get the changes to apply.

Comment: If you mount a folder from the host, the folder overlays the folder in the container. If the host folder is empty it is empty in the container as well.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there a something different I can use that would mirror the host directory and the container directory?

Comment: Where is your main.py file located?